# Toggle the next row in a table

Tags: jquery, toggle, tablerow

I have 3 rows in a table, a header row, an view row, and an edit row. I'm trying to hide the "viewrow" and show the "editrow" from a link in the viewrow.  The viewrow toggles, but the editrow does not.

```
<table width=400 cellpadding=3 cellspacing=2 border=0 align=center>
<tr class="headerrow">
    <td><strong>Field One</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Field Two</strong></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr class="viewrow">
    <td>Item One-One</td>
    <td>Item One-Two</td>
    <td><a href="#" class="edit">Edit</a></td>
</tr>
<form>
<tr class="editrow">
    <td><input type="hidden" name="id" value="1" /><input type="text" name="fieldone" value="Item Two-Two" style="width: 300px;" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="fieldtwo" value="Item One-Two" /></td>
    <td><input type="submit" value="update" name="submit" /></td>
</tr>
</form>
```

And here's the jquery:

```
jQuery(function($) {
$('.edit').click(
function() {
    //hide the view row, and show the edit row
    $(this).closest('tr').toggle();
    $(this).closest('tr').next('.editrow').toggle();
});
});
```

And the CSS:

```
.editrow {
display: none;
}
```

Any thoughts on what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(function($) {
$('.edit').click(
function() {
    //hide the view row, and show the edit row
    $('.viewrow').hide();
     $('.editrow').show();
});
});
```

Try the above

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(function($) {
 $('.edit').click(
  function() {
   //hide the view row, and show the edit row
   $(this).closest('tr').toggle().end()
          .parents('table').find('.editrow').toggle(); 
  });
});
```

this will work as well :)

your code didn't work because you use .next() to find .editrow.

.next() is used to find a siblings element but in your case, .editrow is not a sibling element for .viewrow because is nested in a 'form' element.

Comment: Thank you so much!  The best solution was to put the <form> elements under the <tr> (because there are multiple sets of viewrows & editrows in the actual table, which I simplified [perhaps too much]  for the purpose of this demo) -- But THANK YOU because you put me on the right track!

Comment: Yes, you have right, moving form element is very good solution.

I'm glad I could help :)
Good luck there!